# GFortran I/O error 5002 while reading a direct access file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a little Problem reading a file in Fortran. As you can see I am lopping over a file reading certain records with a specific length.

What happens is, when it comes to a certain record I'm getting an IOSTAT Error 5002. Now my question is what does this error mean: is it end of file or there is no record left or something else? Can I ignore it?

I am using MinGW GFortran 4.8.0.

Here's the code:

```
PROGRAM test_read

INTEGER*4           HCM_error
DOUBLE PRECISION    N_Record(22)
CHARACTER*8         C_Record(22)

EQUIVALENCE         (N_Record,C_Record)

OPEN (UNIT=11, FILE='C:/BORDER/D__HOL.000',STATUS='OLD', ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL=176, ACTION='READ', IOSTAT=IOS)

HCM_error=0

DO N_rec = 1, 2000
    READ (11, REC=N_rec, IOSTAT=IOS) C_Record

    WRITE(*,*) "|",IOS,' ',N_rec,' ',N_record(21),' ',N_record(22),"|"

    !End of file reached (or non existing record) ?
    IF ((IOS .LT. 0) .OR. (IOS .EQ. 36)) EXIT

    IF (IOS .NE. 0) THEN
        !Error in (border-) line data
        HCM_Error = 1049
        EXIT
    END IF
END DO

CLOSE(UNIT=11)

WRITE (*,*) HCM_error 
END PROGRAM
```

Comment: You mean that the value of `ios` is 5002?

Comment: Yes, the value of ios is 5002.

Comment: I tried using IOMSG= and it says Non-existing record number.

Comment: Now I think the Problem is clear - there is no record left. Thanks to @francescalus and his advice to get a descriptive message.

Comment: `integer*4` is not valid Fortran. It was never part of any ISO Fortran standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-zero values returned by an `iostat=` specifier are not portable across compilers.  If you wish to determine what a particular code means then you have two options:

- read the compiler's documentation (if it exists)
- use the `iomsg=` specifier with a character variable

In this case, when you tried `iomsg=` you got the message "Non-existing record number".  So, problem solved.

Well, almost.  There's more to say.

You may be surprised that you are going through records in turn in direct access, but are reaching a "no record" state without first reaching an "end of file" state.  You are testing `(IOS .LT. 0)` with a comment "!End of file reached".

When reading a file connected for direct access, the end of file condition doesn't arise.

What can you do to detect that the record isn't a valid number, beyond the end of the file?  Not much, portably, but any positive number from `iostat=` indicates an error condition.  You know now, though, what this particular `5002` means.

---

I should probably also add that the character variable for `iomsg=` is defined by the transfer statement only if there isn't success.  Consider it only if you know the transfer failed.